# In Kafka, If a client alters the partitions of a topic, Would it create a new topic? Does it cause rebalancing?

Tags: apache-kafka

In Kafka, If a client alters the partitions of a topic, Would it create a new topic? Does it cause rebalancing ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding Partitions doesn't create new topics. It alters the existing one

Data is not rebalanced when expanding cluster or topics partitions

Comment: do you mean, the partition rebalancing wouldn't happen?

Comment: I mean data existing in the topics will not move. What did **you** mean by rebalancing?

Comment: partition rebalancing that will be triggered when a new consumer is added to the existing consumer group or consumer is removed from an existing consumer group.

Comment: Adding partitions will cause consumers to read from new partitions, yes. But they will be empty, meaning you will have idle consumer threads

Comment: Let's say initially, I've 2 partitions and 4 consumers, and after altering the partitions, the partitions became 4, then, i believe there should be partition rebalancing happen so that the existing consumers can consume from the new partitions too. That's why I believe if we alter the no of partitions, it would cause a partition rebalance. This is my understanding. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: We're talking about different things. Consumer group **will** rebalance. Data **already existing** in the topics **will not** spread (or rebalance) to new partitions

Comment: Thanks for the clarification .